# A better way to write these SASS rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I need to overwrite some Bootstrap rules using SASS:

```
.open>.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;

    &:focus, &:hover{
      background-color: transparent;
      color: red;
    }

    &:active:focus{
      outline: 0;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this? Without repeating `background-color` and `color`?

Answer (score 2):

You could extend a placeholder class, similar to a mixin, but the output CSS is cleaner. This would be the recommended approach for smaller things. A placeholder class starts with `%` and doesn't get output in CSS as a single class, but groups all rules that use it so it doesn't get repeat.

```
%red-transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
}
.open>.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{
    @extend %red-and-transparent;

    &:focus, &:hover{
        @extend %red-and-transparent;
    }
}
```

Results in this css

```
.open > .btn-default.dropdown-toggle, .open > .btn-default.dropdown-toggle:focus, .open > .btn-default.dropdown-toggle:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a mixin like this:

```
@mixin red-and-transparent {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
.open>.btn-default.dropdown-toggle{
    @include red-and-transparent;

    &:focus, &:hover{
        @include red-and-transparent;
    }
}
```

But for 2 properties used twice, I wouldn't bother with this and just leave it how you have it now.

Comment: You're right. Is not a situation to create a mixin. 
I was just wondering if I missed any simpler solution. Thanks.